# JQuery: How to simplify classes selection with serial number in event delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create web quiz with each question and option element dynamically generated according to an array.

Below is my script:

```
function showQuestion(){
    for(let i = 0; i < QuesPartA.length; i++){
        $(".questionBox").append('<div class="Question">Number '+ parseInt(i+1) +'</div>');
        $(".questionBox").append('<div class="Options" id="optId'+ parseInt(i+1) +'">');
        QuesPartA[i]['option'].forEach(option => {
            $("#optId"+ parseInt(i+1)).append('<span class ="pilihan'+ parseInt(i+1) +'">'+option +' </span><br>');  
        });
        $(".questionBox").append('</div><br>'); // end Options div
    } 
    $(".secondBox").append('<a href="Listening Part A.html" class="btnToPartB">Continue to Part B</a>'); 
};



function changeColor(){
  $(".questionBox").on("click", ".pilihan1", function() {
    $(this).css("background", "red");
    $('.pilihan1').not(this).css("background", "#ccc");;
  });

  $(".questionBox").on("click", ".pilihan2", function() {
    $(this).css("background", "red");
    $('.pilihan2').not(this).css("background", "#ccc");;
  });

  $(".questionBox").on("click", ".pilihan3", function() {
    $(this).css("background", "red");
    $('.pilihan3').not(this).css("background", "#ccc");;
  });

};
```

The first function is to show the question and answer. The second is to give color to each option when user clicks.

However, the second function is going to be very long since the quiz consists of 30 questions. Is there any ways to do that simpler so that I don't need to write 30 event delegations?

Comment: For starters, the selector does not limit you to one class at a time. Instead of `.on("click", ".pilihan1"`, you can do `.on("click", ".pilihan1, .pilihan2, .pilihan3"`perfectly fine.

Comment: Second, it would probably make much more sense to not try and select these elements by their individual class names to begin with. Give those spans an additional common class.

Comment: I'm intentionally using individual class so that the on(click) function isolated to each ```.Options```, otherwise when user clicks an option and turning it red, the others turn ```#ccc``` regardless of their ```.Options``` parents.

Comment: _"I'm intentionally using individual class so that ..."_ - yeah, that only due to that you are selecting to wide to begin with. `$('.pilihan1')` selects _all_ elements with that class in the whole document - but you can easily limit the scope, by using `$(this).find('.pilihan1')` instead - `$(this)` refers to the `.questionBox` element that you are handling inside your click handler.

Comment: Re: Downvotes, this is not a _good_ question, because it is lacking too much context. We haven't seen any existing HTML this is operating on, we don't have your `QuesPartA` data available either ... So anyone who would want to experiment with your code, could not immediately do so, but would have to create a runable example themselves.  You should always present a [mre] of such issues.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general terms, it's best to completely avoid incremental `id` and `class` attributes in repeated blocks of content, and instead relate them to each other using DOM traversal methods within the relevant event handlers.

In this case, given the implied HTML structure, you can give all the clickable `span` elements the same class and then `find()` them within the `closest()` parent question div.

Also note that the logic can be made more succinct by using `map()` to build the HTML. Try this:

```js
let QuesPartA = [{
  option: [ 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Fizz', 'Buzz' ]
}];


function showQuestion() {
  let questionHtml = QuesPartA.map((question, i) => {
    let optionHtml = question.option.map(opt => `<span class="pilihan">${opt}</span><br />`).join('');
    return `<div class="Question">Number ${i + 1}</div><div class="Options">${optionHtml}</div><br />`;
  }).join(''); 
  
  $(".questionBox").append(questionHtml);
  $(".secondBox").append('<a href="Listening Part A.html" class="btnToPartB">Continue to Part B</a>');
};

function changeColor() {
  $(".questionBox").on("click", ".pilihan", e => {
    let $opt = $(e.target);
    $opt.closest('.Options').find('.pilihan').removeClass('active');
    $opt.addClass('active');
  });
};

showQuestion();
changeColor();
```

```css
.pilihan { color: #CCC; }
.pilihan.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questionBox"></div>
<div class="secondBox"></div>
```

Comment: Wow these things are new to me. Thank you very much. I'm trying to understand the lesson.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You can use set an ID to each button

```
QuesPartA[i]['option'].forEach(option => {
        $("#optId"+ parseInt(i+1)).append('<span id = "'pilihan'+parseInt(i+1)+'" class ="pilihan'+ parseInt(i+1) +'">'+option +' </span><br>');  
    });
```

and use this syntax to add an event to all buttons

```
function changeColor(){
  $(".questionBox").on("click",'[id^=pilihan]', function() {
    $(this).css("background", "red");
    ...
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.